# Is there a way to select an element in Python Selenium that has a dynamic ID?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I have come across a little problem with selenium on Python.
I am trying to click a grid-button, however it does not have a name and the id is dynamic.
For example I can try get_element_by_id("gridcolumn-1260"), but after refreshing the page, it will be some random number (not 1260).

Is there any way that I can always reference the button below?

```
    <div class="x-grid-header-ct  x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct" style="border-width: 1px; width: 628px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 73px;" id="headercontainer-1129" tabindex="0">
   <div id="headercontainer-1129-innerCt" data-ref="innerCt" role="presentation" class="x-box-inner" style="width: 1341px; height: 29px;">
      <div id="headercontainer-1129-targetEl" data-ref="targetEl" class="x-box-target" role="presentation" style="width: 1341px;">
         <div class="x-column-header x-column-header-checkbox x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-column-header-first" style="border-width: 1px; width: 24px; right: auto; left: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1260" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1260">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1260-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner x-column-header-inner-empty"><span id="gridcolumn-1260-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">&nbsp;</span></div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 24px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1130" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1130">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1130-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1130-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Last Name</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1130-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 174px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1131" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1131">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1131-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1131-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">First Name</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1131-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 324px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1132" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1132">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1132-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1132-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Username</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1132-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; width: 100px; right: auto; left: 474px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1133" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1133">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1133-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1133-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Status</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1133-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; width: 150px; right: auto; left: 574px; margin: 0px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1134" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1134">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1134-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1134-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Type</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1134-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 724px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1135" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1135">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1135-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1135-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Title</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1135-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 874px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1136" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1136">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1136-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1136-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Phone</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1136-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header  x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 1024px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1137" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1137">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1137-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1137-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Primary Email</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1137-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="x-column-header x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-column-header-last" style="border-width: 1px; right: auto; left: 1174px; margin: 0px; width: 150px; top: 0px;" id="gridcolumn-1138" tabindex="-1" componentid="gridcolumn-1138">
            <div id="gridcolumn-1138-titleEl" data-ref="titleEl" class="x-column-header-inner">
               <span id="gridcolumn-1138-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-column-header-text">Location</span>
               <div id="gridcolumn-1138-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" class="x-column-header-trigger" style=""></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide (preferably) a URL or otherwise more of the HTML with the exact element you wish to get?

Comment: I added more, I am trying to get 'gridcolumn-1260' in this  case.